# international function names in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, ole, regional-settings

I am writing a file conversion tool using oleautomation within dBase to make Excel change data formats (mostly dates and numbers to get a standardized format). With English versions of Excel I do the following:

`oExcel.range("A:A").select()

oExcel.selection.numberformat="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"`

The above works fine, but if a French user runs the code with French regional settings, his local Excel has aaaa-mm-jj hh:mm:ss for that same date format based on the French names for year and day.

Same for formula's like average() = moyenne() in French.

Is there some place in the registry or in some Excel array that I can query what the local language equivalent is for the English function names? I'd really like to avoid creating my own arrays for each language supported in my tool and I would hope that MS does not create a different set of functions for each language but rather has some sort of mapping stored somewhere that  points to the English function name...

Cheers,
Gaetano.

Comment: it seems that there is a file named VBALIST.XLS or .XLS3 or XLS4 under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\1036 or 1040. It has the list of functions and their translation into another language if you have an English version of office, and it has a translation between a non-English language to English if you own a non-English version of Office. However, I doubt that Excel uses that for its operations, so I am hoping that someone knows how to get the info programmatically without needing to search for different file names under different folders that may have different structures